# So I am having trouble reversing my string, it reverses everything but something weird happens in the middle

Tags: c

```
void reverse(char str[]){
    char temp;
    int i;
    int k = size(str);
    int len = size(str)/2;

    for(i= 0; i<len; i++){
         temp = str[k];
         str[k] = str[i];
         str[i] = temp;
         k--;
         if(len==k){
           break;
            }
    }//for loop
    printf("%s\n", str);
 }//reverse
```

for string
"Chrisitian is my name"
I keep getting
"eman ym s inaitsirhC"

the problem is with the space and 'i' in "is".

It might be the way i am reading in the string or my for loops.

size(str[]) just returns the size of the string.

Comment: what function is size()?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Try some test cases with strings like 123456 and 12345. Use both odd and even lengths of strings and think how the loop should proceed in either case. Check that the size() function call is giving the right result. Or is there a more reliable call like strlen(). At first glance that first access of temp = str[k] in the loop doesn't look right, if k is the number of chars in the string and the array access is zero based. The last element should be k-1.

Comment: Is `size()` working as expected? If I have `str = "adam"`, does your `size()` function return `3`? It seems you are using the return value of `size()` to index into `str`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
     if(len==k){
       break;
        }
```

This breaks the loop one cycle too soon.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be this:

```
void reverse(char *str)
  {
    char temp;      /* Temp Variable */
    int i;          /* Loop Counter */
    int ltc;        /* Loop Terminus Count */
    int len;        /* String Length */

    len = strlen(str);
    ltc = len >> 1;
    len--;

    for (i = 0; i < ltc; i++)
      {
        temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[len - i];
        str[len - i] = temp;
      }
  }
```

This will work.  I use this exact code when I need to reverse a string for some reason.  The reason for `len--` is so that you don't swap the NULL byte.  The line `ltc = len >> 1` is a quick and dirty divide by 2, without using an actual divide, but a shift left.

As for your code, you don't really need the if statement there because the loop will already terminate when it reaches halfway down the string, same with mine.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char* str);

int main()
{
    reverse("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char* str)
{
   char temp;
   int i = 0;
   int j = strlen(str) - 1;

   while (i < j) {
      temp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[j];
      str[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return;
 }//reverse
```